# Customising ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have some data and would like to plot the forecasts and 95% prediction intervals using ggplot. The following code works and gives an acceptable legend.

```
ExampleData = data.frame(t = 1:10, f = rep(1,10), Lower = rep(0.5, 10), Upper = rep(1.5, 10))
library (ggplot2)
ggplot(data = ExampleData)+
  geom_point(aes(x=t, y =f, colour = "Forecasts"))+
  geom_point(aes(x=t, y =Lower), shape=95)+
  geom_segment(aes(x=t, y = Lower, xend=t, yend = f))+
  geom_point(aes(x=t, y =Upper), shape=95)+
  geom_segment(aes(x=t, y = f, xend=t, yend = Upper))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 11, colour = "95% PI"))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("95% PI" = "black","Forecasts" = "red"),
                      guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
                        linetype = c('solid','blank'),
                        shape = c(NA,16))))+
  scale_x_continuous(name="Time", limits=c(1, 10), breaks = c(0,5,10))+
  labs(title="Example")+
  labs(y = "Forecasts")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image: rplot of the example]

I would also like to add a horizontal line, at say `y = 0.75`. However, the legend does not seem to be able to accommodate a horizontal and vertical line. Is there a way that I can use ggplot to do this? What about including shorter, horizontal lines, also? For example, the upper and lower points are represented by short horizontal lines.

Comment: welcome to SO. +1 for providing a reproducible code. Well done. I suggest to add the image generated from this code in your question too. I would have done it but I'm on a slow internet connection.

Comment: Your example does not show vertical line with `geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 11, colour = "95% PI"))` because you use narrower limits for x-axis. You can add horizontal line with simply `geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.75, colour = "95% PI"))` (this makes cross in legend) or just use `geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0.75))`. Shorter lines can be drawn with `geom_segment()`

Comment: @Adela. Thank you for the reply. However, I am aware of your suggestions already. The reason that I added the vertical line was to include a vertical line in the legend (representing the prediction intervals). I do not want a vertical line in the plot. I also understand that you can add a horizontal line the way that you mentioned. The problem being, like you mentioned, the legend makes a cross. I would like the legend to add a horizontal line representing a threshold that I would like to add; and also a vertical line representing the prediction intervals.

Comment: I see your problem now. See this discussion: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1267

Comment: @Adela. The discussion seems to be closed with no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated @Slagt answer to include points into legend:

```
library (ggplot2)
ExampleData = data.frame(t = 1:10, f = 1, Lower = 0.5, Upper = 1.5)

ggplot(data = ExampleData, aes(x = t)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper, color = "95% PI"), width = 0) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = f, color = "Forecasts")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = 0.75, color = "Threshold")) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("95% PI"    = "black",
                                 "Forecasts"  = "red",
                                 "Threshold" = "green"),
                      guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
                        linetype = c("blank", "blank", "solid"),
                        shape    = c(124, 16, NA),
                        size     = c(5, 1.5, 0.5)))) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_continuous(name="Time", breaks = c(0, 5, 10)) + 
  labs(title = "Example", y = "Forecasts")
```

[image]

The special shape for vertical line is very nice hack. However, it should be also possible to rotate the line in legend. This can be done when you modify `GeomErrorbar$draw_key` and `GeomLine$draw_key` functions:

```
library(grid)
GeomErrorbar$draw_key <- function(data, params, size) 
{
  segmentsGrob(x0 = 0.5, y0 = 0, x1 = 0.5, y1 = 1, 
               gp = gpar(col = alpha(data$colour, data$alpha), 
                         lwd = data$size * .pt, 
                         lty = ifelse(data$colour == "green", 
                                      0, data$linetype), 
                         lineend = "butt"))
}
GeomLine$draw_key <- function(data, params, size) 
{
  segmentsGrob(x0 = 0, y0 = 0.5, x1 = 1, y1 = .5, 
               gp = gpar(col = alpha(data$colour, data$alpha), 
                         lwd = data$size * .pt, 
                         lty = ifelse(data$colour == "black", 
                                      0, data$linetype), 
                         lineend = "butt"))
}
```

For `geom_errorbar` I set the legend line to be vertical and for `geom_line` to be horizontal. To prevent crossing effect I add a condition for `lty` argument based on colour.

And then simply create plot:

```
ggplot(data = ExampleData, aes(x = t)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper, color = "95% PI"), 
                width = 0) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = f, color = "Forecasts")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = 0.75, color = "Threshold")) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("95% PI"    = "black",
                                 "Forecasts"  = "red",
                                 "Threshold" = "green"),
                      guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
                        linetype = c("solid", "blank", "solid"),
                        shape = c(NA, 16, NA)))) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_continuous(name="Time", breaks = c(0, 5, 10)) + 
  labs(title = "Example") + labs(y = "Forecasts")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Update taking into account OP's comment:

If the aesthetics `color`, `fill`, `group`, ... are defined, the element is automatically added to the legend. Therefore, something like `geom_line(aes(color = 'foo'))` will produce a legend element named *foo*, but `geom_line(color = 'black')` won't.

```
library (ggplot2)
ExampleData = data.frame(t = 1:10, f = 1, Lower = 0.5, Upper = 1.5)

g <- ggplot(data = ExampleData, aes(x = t))

g <- g + geom_point(aes(y = f, color = "95% PI"), size = 0)
g <- g + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper, color = "95% PI"))
g <- g + geom_point(aes(y = f), color = "red")
g <- g + geom_line(aes(y = 0.75, color = "Threshold"))

g <- g + scale_colour_manual(values = c("95% PI"    = "black",
                                        "Threshold" = "green"),
                             guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
                               linetype = c('blank', 'solid'),
                               shape    = c('|',      NA),
                               size     = c(5,        0.5))))

g <- g + theme_bw()
g <- g + scale_x_continuous(name="Time", breaks = c(0, 5, 10))
g <- g + labs(title = "Example")
g <- g + labs(y = "Forecasts")

print(g)
```

This will produce an output like this:
[image: Results of the RPlot above]

To get the vertical line in the legend, I added an invisible `geom_point` (size to 0, see below for the reason of this). Note that the `color` aesthetics is defined, therefore the legend will be populated by this element. To add an horizontal line to the plot at fix *y* value, and to the legend, the easiest is to use a `geom_line` element *and* to set the `color` aesthetics. Finally, to display the red points and exclude them from the legend, you must *not* set the `color` aesthetics.

```
g <- g + geom_point(aes(y = f, color = "95% PI"), size = 0)
g <- g + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper, color = "95% PI"))
g <- g + geom_line(aes(y = 0.75, color = "Threshold"))
g <- g + geom_point(aes(y = f), color = "red")
```

Regarding the legend, to have a vertical bar, rather than an horizontal bar (default), you can use the shape `|`. This is a rather small shape by default (at least on my computer), so you may have to increase its size a bit. You can do this by playing with the guides. Note that `geom_errorbar` or `geom_segment` do *not* have the `shape` property. To use a shape rather than a line, you need to add the invisible `geom_point` first.

```
g <- g + scale_colour_manual(values = c("95% PI"    = "black",
                                        "Threshold" = "green"),
                             guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
                               linetype = c('blank', 'solid'),
                               shape    = c('|',      NA),
                               size     = c(5,        0.5))))
```

### Previous answer:

Assuming you want the points, vertical segments, the horizontal segments and the horizontal lines all in the legend, here is my suggestion:

```
ExampleData = data.frame(t = 1:10, f = rep(1,10), Lower = rep(0.5, 10), Upper = rep(1.5, 10))
library (ggplot2)

tipw <- 0.2
g <- ggplot(data = ExampleData)

g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = t, y = Lower, xend = t, yend = Upper, color = "95% PI"))
g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = t - tipw / 2, y = Lower, xend = t + tipw / 2, yend = Lower, color = "Minimum"))
g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = t - tipw / 2, y = Upper, xend = t + tipw / 2, yend = Upper, color = "Maximum"))
g <- g + geom_point(aes(x = t, y = f, color = "Forecasts"))
g <- g + geom_line(aes(x = t, y = 0.75, color = "Some value"))

g <- g + scale_x_continuous(name="Time", limits=c(1 - tipw/2, 10 + tipw/2), breaks = c(0, 5, 10))
g <- g + labs(title = "Example")
g <- g + labs(y = "Forecasts")

g <- g + scale_colour_manual(values = c("95% PI"     = "black",
                                        "Forecasts"  = "red",
                                        "Minimum"    = "orange",
                                        "Maximum"    = "green",
                                        "Some value" = "light blue"),
                             guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
                                     linetype = c('solid', 'blank', 'solid', 'solid', 'solid'),
                                     shape    = c(NA,      16,      NA,      NA,      NA))))
g <- g + theme_bw()

print(g)
```

[image: Rplot of the example]

```
tipw <- 0.2
g <- ggplot(data = ExampleData)
```

Creates the plot with your data. The `tipw` variable is the width of the tips (using the same unit as the *x-axis*). See below.

```
g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = t, y = Lower, xend = t, yend = Upper, color = "95% PI"))
g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = t - tipw / 2, y = Lower, xend = t + tipw / 2, yend = Lower, color = "Minimum"))
g <- g + geom_segment(aes(x = t - tipw / 2, y = Upper, xend = t + tipw / 2, yend = Upper, color = "Maximum"))
g <- g + geom_point(aes(x = t, y = f, color = "Forecasts"))
g <- g + geom_line(aes(x = t, y = 0.75, color = "Some value"))
```

Adds the lines, segments and points. The elements will be stacked in the order you write them. So here the short horizontal bars at the tips will be drawn first, then the vertical bar, then the points on top of the bars and then the arbitrary horizontal line on top of the rest.

Remember you can do some logic in aesthetics of ggplot. The short horizontal bars are defined here as segments starting from `x = t - tipw / 2` and ending to `x = t + tipw / 2`. The long horizontal bar can be manually defined to `y = 0.75`. This works because you can always use a vector of length 1 for aesthetics and the value will be used for all points (`aes(x = t, y = 0.75)` gives the same result as `aes(x = t, y = rep(0.75, length(t)))`).

```
g <- g + scale_x_continuous(name = "Time", limits=c(1 - tipw/2, 10 + tipw/2), breaks = c(0, 5, 10))
```

You must include the *xstart* and *xend* of the horizontal segments for them to be drawn. That's why the limits are extended by `tipw/2`. Otherwise the horizontal bar on the far left and far right won't be visible, and a warning will be thrown.

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_segment). 
2: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

Comment: I think there may be some misunderstanding of my question. I understand how to create the plots. The issue that I am having is with the legend. I would like the legend to have a vertical line representing the prediction intervals, and a horizontal line to represent a threshold. 

If that is not possible, I would like to include smaller horizontal lines in the legend to represent the upper and lower points of the prediction intervals. This would mean that the legend has a long horizontal line representing a threshold and shorter horizontal lines representing upper and lower points.

Comment: The line which adds "scale_colour_manual" produces the following error when I try to run it 

"Error in if (nchar(shape_string[1]) <= 1) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed".

Comment: You can use the shape number 124 instead of the character '|'. It should solve the issue here.